# Delete a row in DataGridView Control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am working on DataGridView control in vb.net. I need help you that i want
to delete a row in datagrid and only that row deleted who selected.
Mean first i select the row then row deleted.
So please provide me code that how i select and delete row from
DataGridView control in VB.NET

thank

Comment: Which are you using WPF, Winforms or ASP.NET?

Comment: in vb.net desktop application

Comment: by desktop application you mean WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In yourDGV.SelectedRows
    yourDGV.Rows.Remove(row)
Next
```

This will delete all rows that had been selected.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Windows forms, you could allow the user to select a row and in the delete key click event. It is recommended that you allow the user to select 1 row only and not a group of rows (myDataGridView.MultiSelect = false)

```
Private Sub pbtnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

        If myDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            'you may want to add a confirmation message, and if the user confirms delete
            myDataGridView.Rows.Remove(myDataGridView.SelectedRows(0))
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Select 1 row before you hit Delete")
        End If

    End Sub
```

Note that this will not delete the row form the database until you perform the delete in the database.

Answer (score -2):

```vb
If dgv(11, dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Selected = True Then
    dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(dgv.CurrentRow.Index)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Please format the code as a code, and also need some details about what this code does.