# VB.net add and remove data from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

how to remove data from datagridview..

im using this syntax on button to add data to datagridview..

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(num, TextBox1.Text, id_jenis, harga)
```

But.. how is the remove syntax to remove selected row on datagridview ?

Comment: Take a look at this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200315/delete-a-row-in-datagridview-control-in-vb-net. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use .Remove or .RemoveAt

```
MyDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(index)
```

then, if you would like to remove selected row, you can previously store the row index using datagridview events like,

```
Private index as Integer = 0

    Private Sub MyDataGridView_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView.CellClick

        index = e.RowIndex

    End Sub
```